# Macro to update comments already present in master sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro that will import data from a sub sheet to a master sheet. The cells that the data will populate will already have values in them, so the data being copied will need to be added to the data already present. I know how to find and select the data in the sub sheet; the problem is adding the sub sheet data to the data that already exists in the master file. It is a range of 11 cells all in one column. Additionally, I need the comments that are entered in the sub sheet cells to be pasted into the master sheet, but not overwrite the comments already there. Instead, they need to paste below the previous comment entries. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Using Record Macro as proof of concept

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=1+RC[1]"
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=2+RC[1]"
Range("A3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=3+RC[1]"
Range("B1").Select
Range("B1").Comment.Text Text:="Fourth comment." & Chr(10) & ""
Range("A1").Select
Range("A1").Comment.Text Text:="first comment." & Chr(10) & "Fourth comment." & Chr(10) & ""
Range("B2").Select
Range("B2").Comment.Text Text:="Fifth comment."
Range("A2").Select
Range("A2").Comment.Text Text:="Second comment." & Chr(10) & "Fifth comment." & Chr(10) & ""
Range("B3").Select
Range("B3").Comment.Text Text:="Sixth comment." & Chr(10) & ""
Range("A3").Select
Range("A3").Comment.Text Text:="Third coment." & Chr(10) & "Sixth comment." & Chr(10) & ""
Range("D8").Select
End Sub
```

this takes Sheet1 data with comments of "Fifth comment." in B2 and results in Sheet2:

[image: SO17712306 example]

Comment: This makes sense but it appears that this method cannot deal with comments that are changing, i.e. the program must know what the comment says beforehand instead of importing it.